# How to find built-in function source code in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to do research on batch normalization, and had to make some modifications for the pytorch BN code. I dig into the pytorch code and got stuck with `torch.nn.functional.batch_norm`, which references [`torch.batch_norm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/functional.html#batch_norm).

The problem is that `torch.batch_norm` cannot be further found in the torch library. Is there any way I can find the source code of this built-in function and re-implement it? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's there, but it's not defined in Python. They're defined in C++ in the `aten/` directories.

For CPU, the implementation (one of them, it depends on whether or not the input is contiguous) is here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/420b37f3c67950ed93cd8aa7a12e673fcfc5567b/aten/src/ATen/native/Normalization.cpp#L61-L126

For CUDA, the implementation is here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7aae51cdedcbf0df5a7a8bf50a947237ac4b3ee8/aten/src/ATen/native/cudnn/BatchNorm.cpp#L52-L143

Comment: Thanks, it perfectly solved my problem. Though I'm still curious how did you precisely knew where the code is. Is there like a mapping between them?

Comment: There's no mapping I know of. I just searched the repository on GitHub for `batch_norm` and looked through the results manually. I kept an eye out for the `/aten` folder since that's where most of C++ source lives.