# How to implement Batchnorm2d in Pytorch myself?

Tags: python, pytorch, batch-normalization

I'm trying to implement Batchnorm2d() layer with:

```
class BatchNorm2d(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, num_features):
        super(BatchNorm2d, self).__init__()
        self.num_features = num_features
        device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        self.eps = 1e-5
        self.momentum = 0.1
        self.first_run = True

    def forward(self, input):
        # input: [batch_size, num_feature_map, height, width]
        device = input.device
        if self.training:
            mean = torch.mean(input, dim=0, keepdim=True).to(device)  # [1, num_feature, height, width]
            var = torch.var(input, dim=0, unbiased=False, keepdim=True).to(device)  # [1, num_feature, height, width]
            if self.first_run:
                self.weight = Parameter(torch.randn(input.shape, dtype=torch.float32, device=device), requires_grad=True)
                self.bias = Parameter(torch.randn(input.shape, dtype=torch.float32, device=device), requires_grad=True)
                self.register_buffer('running_mean', torch.zeros(input.shape).to(input.device))
                self.register_buffer('running_var', torch.ones(input.shape).to(input.device))
                self.first_run = False
            self.running_mean = (1 - self.momentum) * self.running_mean + self.momentum * mean
            self.running_var = (1 - self.momentum) * self.running_var + self.momentum * var
            bn_init = (input - mean) / torch.sqrt(var + self.eps)
        else:
            bn_init = (input - self.running_mean) / torch.sqrt(self.running_var + self.eps)
        return self.weight * bn_init + self.bias
```

But after training & testing I found that the results using my layer is incomparable with the results using `nn.Batchnorm2d()`. There must be something wrong with it, and I guess the problem relates to initializing parameters in `forward()`? I did that because I don't know how to know the shape of input in `__init__()`, maybe there is a better way.  I don't know how to fix it, please help. Thanks!!

Comment: I'd recommend you to take a look at the [original implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/batchnorm.py).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got answers from [HERE](http://d2l.ai/chapter_convolutional-modern/batch-norm.html?highlight=batchnorm2d)!\
So the shape of weight(bias) is (1, num_features, 1, 1), not (1, num_features, width, height).

Answer (score 1):

Just if someone stumbles on this,
you don't actually have to set the 'device' inside the model as done above. Outside the model, you can just do

```
device = torch.device('cuda:0')
model = model.to(device)
```

not sure if this is better than manually setting devices for weights and biases inside the module, but definitely more standard I think

Answer (score 1):

The [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6sfmUTpUmc) from Andrej Karpathy has a very intuitive explanation.

Here is a code snippet with the 1D implementation, from the [notebook](https://github.com/karpathy/nn-zero-to-hero/blob/master/lectures/makemore/makemore_part3_bn.ipynb) associated with the video:

```
class BatchNorm1d:
  
  def __init__(self, dim, eps=1e-5, momentum=0.1):
    self.eps = eps
    self.momentum = momentum
    self.training = True
    # parameters (trained with backprop)
    self.gamma = torch.ones(dim)
    self.beta = torch.zeros(dim)
    # buffers (trained with a running 'momentum update')
    self.running_mean = torch.zeros(dim)
    self.running_var = torch.ones(dim)
  
  def __call__(self, x):
    # calculate the forward pass
    if self.training:
      xmean = x.mean(0, keepdim=True) # batch mean
      xvar = x.var(0, keepdim=True) # batch variance
    else:
      xmean = self.running_mean
      xvar = self.running_var
    xhat = (x - xmean) / torch.sqrt(xvar + self.eps) # normalize to unit variance
    self.out = self.gamma * xhat + self.beta
    # update the buffers
    if self.training:
      with torch.no_grad():
        self.running_mean = (1 - self.momentum) * self.running_mean + self.momentum * xmean
        self.running_var = (1 - self.momentum) * self.running_var + self.momentum * xvar
    return self.out
  
  def parameters(self):
    return [self.gamma, self.beta]
```

The pytorch implementation is in [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58193798/how-to-find-built-in-function-source-code-in-pytorch).

However, this implementation + explanation, from [Dive into deep learning](http://d2l.ai/chapter_convolutional-modern/batch-norm.html#implementation-from-scratch) website, as mentioned in the approved answer, might help you understand the implementation difference between 1D and 2D case.